# Importing whole SVG images folder from another direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to import whole folder with my SVG icons from another direction. For now i know how to import a single file one by one. Want to import the whole folder, to make code cleaner and to faster implementation.

Tryed to do this like this
`import Icon from '../../icons'`

but that's not the right way i guess.

```
import './WeatherBox.css'
import Icon from '../../icons'

const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
}

const WeatherBox = ({result}) => {
    return (
        <div className="locationDate">
            <span>{result.location}</span>
            <span>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</span>
            <span>{result.temp}°C</span>
            <img src={Icon.clear} alt=""/>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using React, you're most likely using webpack as well.
You must reference all icons in the code, or they won't be available later. You could put them in a static directory and then fetch them that way. Meaning you send a HTTP GET request to `/static/directory/${icon}.svg`, this way you can load them without having to reference them.

Another solution is to mention them in the code, for example you can create an index.js file inside the `icons` directory with the following code:

```
import clear from './clear.svg';

export const Icons = {
  clear,
}
```

This way you can do the following inside your code:

```
import { Icons } from '../../icons';
Icons.clear // URL to the svg
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Icons are in jsx format the way you do is correct. You can import them like any other component in jsx or tsx format